# Director::getInstance()->getTouchDispatcher() is giving error that no member named getTouchDispatcher() in cocos2d::Director in cocos2d 3.9

Tags: ios, c++11, xcode6, cocos2d-x

please give me some alternate solution of this 
**onEnter()** Method

```
{
   Director::getInstance()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, false);

    Layer::onEnter();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cocos2d 3.9, you can use blocks as explained below to detect touches. You can write below code in onEnter. For more details, check cocos2d-x programming guide: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/8/index.html

```
//  Create a "one by one" touch event listener
// (processes one touch at a time)
auto listener1 = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

// trigger when you push down
listener1->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){
    // your code
    return true; // if you are consuming it
};

// trigger when moving touch
listener1->onTouchMoved = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){
    // your code
};

// trigger when you let up
listener1->onTouchEnded = [=](Touch* touch, Event* event){
    // your code
};

// Add listener
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener1, this);
```